# Perl GUI App - Creating Exe

Tags: perl, exe

I have written in GUI application in Perl. Now I want to create executable for Windows. I searched and I came to know that we can use Perl2Exe, PerlApp and Par-Packer. But first two are paid. Third one i.e Perl Par are suggested by many people even in this forum. But the problem I didnt know how to use this. I am using Activestate Perl 5.10. I dont find Par-Packer in PPM. In one of the thread, someone suggested to install Mingw using PPM and the install Par-Packer using cpan. But even I cant install Mingw because I dont find in PPM. So I left with no option. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** For people who may end up here, please use [Cava Packer](http://www.cavapackager.com/download.html) if want to create Executable for your perl script.

Comment: I just tried Cava Packer - fantastic utility! I just spent over an hour searching the web for a solution, and of course came across the same first 3 options as you did. When I tried PAR, it threw an error that I couldn't find an answer to. Cava Packer installed and worked smoothly; the GUI and project structure were the icing on the cake. Highly recommended.

Comment: Cava also creates an installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find Par::Packer PPMs in other PPM repositories.  The easiest place to find where a PPM can be found is on kobesearch.

[The kobesearch listing for Par::Packer](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/search?query=Par%3a%3aPacker&mode=dist) shows Version 0.991 PPMs are available at the bribes PPM repository, 1.008 is at Trouchelle, and 0.977 at uwinnepeg.

Just add the Trouchelle repo to your PPM sources list, and you can install easily.

Comment: @daotoad I added repo and again I searched for PAR-Packer but its not showing up in ppm. From PPM, I installed par. But When I tried pp in cmd prompt, I am getting "pp is not recognized as an internal or external command". Even I searched in sit/bin/ folder but pp.bat is not found. What shall I do now? Please help

Comment: @Winbros, I don't have a windows system to test with.  The `pp` program is part of the Par::Packer distro.  What should happen is you add the repo with the command `ppm rep add trouchelle.com http://trouchelle.com/ppm10/`, then when you list modules, you should see many new modules that weren't available before--including Par-Packer.  You should then be able to install Par-Packer.

Comment: @Winbros,   FWIW, when I was doing a lot of this stuff, I used PerlApp, and it worked great.  My benchmarking showed that apps started up faster than Par-Packed files.  Cava packager ( http://www.cava.co.uk/ ) has turned into a viable option since then, too.   It is free for non-commercial use.  Check it out.

Comment: @daotoad Cava Packager works great. It seems I have to spend some more time to get used to this Cava. Can you please tell me how to hide console window which appears when clicking on exe which was generate by Cava.

Comment: @Winbros, not sure with Cava, but there is a box to check in PerlApp, and a command line switch with `pp`.

Comment: @daotoad I find out how to do using Cava. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I found them, but either I have hard to time instaling in Perl distribution or par is not working once installed.

Comment: @Aftershock, why don't you ask another question about how to install PAR::Packer?  Be sure to tell us what version Perl you are using, and the steps you followed to install pp, and then the error messages you got.  There are too many details to address in a comment.  Also, more eyes will find your question than if it is buried in a comment.  So, try asking a new question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) isn't a Perl module that you install via PPM, it's a system that would allow you to compile another version of Perl that you'd then use to install [`Par::Packer`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/).

Comment: Can you please explain the procedure for creating exe in brief?

Comment: @Winbros: Unfortunately I can't, as I have never done that before. `Par::Packer`'s documentation looks fairly good though; you shouldn't have much trouble following that.

Comment: Ok Let me give a try. Thanks for your help